# How can I build GPUMlib on Fedora 20?

Tags: compilation, machine-learning, gpu

[GPUMlib](http://gpumlib.sourceforge.net/) comes with a filed called `CMakeLists.txt` instead of Makefiles or configure scripts.  I do not see any build instructions and I do not see a list of packages that need to be installed in order to build GPUMlib even in the [sources](http://sourceforge.net/p/gpumlib/code/ci/default/tree/).

Comment: `CMakeLists.txt` is your Makefile. You may want to get familiar with `cmake`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer assumes that cmake and gcc et al are already installed.

First install [the CULA tools](http://www.culatools.com/downloads/dense/).  [Their documentation](http://www.culatools.com/cula_dense_programmers_guide/) doesn't seem mention it, but their installer (which is barely mentioned in their [FAQ](http://www.culatools.com/dense/faq/)) worked for me.

Once the installer finishes, it'll report some important shell variables, namely `CULA_LIB_PATH_32`, `CULA_LIB_PATH_64`, and `CULA_INC_PATH`.  Take note of their values.

Invoke cmake with the shell variables reported by the CULA installer.  Using me as an example, I installed my CULA tools at `/home/john/projects/gpumlib/cula` and cloned the gpumlib code into a directory called `gpumlib-code` so then my cmake command looked like this:

```
CULA_LIB_PATH_32=/home/john/projects/gpumlib/cula/lib CULA_LIB_PATH_64=/home/john/projects/gpumlib/cula/lib64 CULA_INC_PATH=/home/john/projects/gpumlib/cula/include cmake gpumlib-code
make -j 8
```

I wrote a bash script to do this for me which looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

export CULA_LIB_PATH_32=/home/john/projects/gpumlib/cula/lib
export CULA_LIB_PATH_64=/home/john/projects/gpumlib/cula/lib64
export CULA_INC_PATH=/home/john/projects/gpumlib/cula/include

cmake gpumlib-code

make -j 8
```

Thanks to Noel de Jesus Mendonça Lopes (the author of gpumlib) for helping me.